# Табличная задачка по python

Tags: python

Она меня вообще в угол загнала. Ничего не понял, понимаю , что нагло, но никогда в таком тупике не был. Как считать? Что за N - 1 в условии? Очень запутанно. Прошу не решение, а помощь в объяснении.

Пусть вновь имеются N станций и таблица цен на проезд между ними. Требуется найти все такие пары станций, для которых дешевле проехать от одной до другой с одной пересадкой через какую-то третью станцию, чем напрямую.
Формат ввода

Формат Ввода
На первой строке вводится натуральное число N — количество станций.
Далее следует N-1 строка, составляющая половину таблицы цен, как в предыдущих задачах на эту тему.
Формат вывода

Формат Вывода
Выводится список пар номеров станций, удовлетворяющих условию (каждая пара — через пробел). Пары должны быть отсортированы по возрастанию по первому номеру, затем — по второму, и пары не должны повторяться, в том числе с изменённым порядком номеров в паре.

Comment: Если N это например 22, то N-1 будет 21

Comment: Скажем, станций 3. Даём для станции 1 цены на поездку на станции 2 и 3. Даём для станции 2 цену на поездку на станцию 3. Всё. Двух строк достаточно. Для станции 3 цены не нужны - они все уже известны.

Comment: @Akina Хорошо, но как можно считать меньшую цену, ведь то что я получаю это или матрица или словарь с ценами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так в (случайной) матрице цен выглядит путь от станции `B` до станции `E` (или обратно) через станцию `D`. Стоимость такой поездки равна 35+3=38.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остальное, по-моему, совершенно очевидно.

Например, в этой матрице пути от станции `B` до станции `E` через станции `A`..`F` имеют стоимости 75, 35, 100, 38, 35, 72. Минимальное значение - 35, оно соответствует путям через станции `B` и `E` - то есть прямому пути, без промежуточной станции. Если же промежуточная станция обязательна, то минимальная стоимость - 38, через станцию `D`.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно если у нас 3 станции, то матрица расстояний выглядит например так

```
0 1 4
1 0 3
4 3 0
```

Соответственно на вход подаются строки

```
1
4 3
```

Для решения задачи можно использовать основную идею алгоритма Дейкстры.

Comment: Я же написал: основную идею.